# how to configure nginx to use SSL Certificate in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, encryption

https://www.petercuret.com/how-ssl-encrypt-your-django-heroku-projects-free-lets-encrypt/

This article about encrypt django app  is a great tutorial. I did most of the process, except the last one. "Adding the security certificate to Heroku", mine is cloud server with Ubuntu 16.04. So it's not adapted to my server.

Googled around about "Nginx ssl encrypt", and found this tutorial（https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I configured nginx server as this tutorial. When all finished, I tested it with "curl https://example.com(my domain)", it returns "Failed to connect to example.com port 443: Connection refused"

PS: nginx runs in host, and Django app runs in a docker container

Some results of my server:

```
root@i-atbxncfv:~# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6) 




root@i-atbxncfv:~# sudo ufw app list
Available applications:
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH


root@i-atbxncfv:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                NAMES
b082bf17c218        e5b11bf09f49        "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:21->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32789->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32788->5000/tcp   django_app_1


root@i-atbxncfv:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# cat example-com.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://0.0.0.0:32788;
    }
}


root@i-atbxncfv:/etc/nginx/sites-available# cat default
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
        server_name test.doask.net;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    # SSL configuration
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
}


server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-test.doask.net.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
```

Comment: not sure what this tutorial is about, but I see your `example-com.conf` file only listens on port 80 and not on 443. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks like your nginx config doesn't include a "listen 443" and no link to serve the certificate. I personally like this guide, it helps a lot: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-3-configure-tlsssl-on-web-server-(nginx)

Comment: @MihaiZamfir Thanks, 443 is configured to in another conf file. Check the updated version.

Comment: @damio Thanks, It seems that, we have the same tutorial. It's just a link in my previous version, I updated to highlight the link.